# Можно ли используя Scene Kit и UIGestureRecognizer вращать объект свайпами?

Tags: swift

Подключена 3D модель человека через Scene Kit. Возможно ли используя жест свайпа задать действие вращение объекта допустим на 180 градусов вокруг одной оси?
Подключил жест свайпа как Action и вписал туда следующую строку кода:

```
@IBAction func objectSwipeRight(_ sender: Any) {

SCNAction.rotateBy(x: -100, y: 43, z: 0, duration: 1)


}
```

Но ничего не происходит. Заранее говорю что только в процессе изучения Swift'a  и прошу строго не ругать =)

Answer (score 0):

[Документация](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnactionable) говорит что после создания и настройки SCNAction вам нужно вызвать метод

```
func runAction(_ action: SCNAction)
```

у вашего SKNode объекта, и все должно заработать, будет выглядеть примерно так

```
@IBAction func objectSwipeRight(_ sender: Any) {

     let rotateAction = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: -100, y: 43, z: 0, duration: 1) // создаем екшн

     self.humanNode.runAction(rotateAction) //передаем его в ноду

}
```

---

А если сделать так

```
@IBAction func objectSwipeRight(_ sender: Any) {

     let rotateAction = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: -100, y: 43, z: 0, duration: 1) // создаем екшн

     let humanInfinite = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Infinite", recursively: true)

     humanInfinite.runAction(rotateAction) //передаем его в ноду

}
```

---

вот как ноду подцепить

```
 Class {

 var humanInfinite: SCNNode?

 func viewDidLoad(_ animated:Bool) {
     super.viewDidLoad(animated)
     self.humanInfinite = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Infinite", recursively: true)
 }

 }
```

после чего можно обращатся к ноде :

```
self.humanInfinite?
```

Comment: поставил все так, не определяет ноду "Use of unresolved identifier"

Comment: Ну так я же не знаю как вы году подключали как вы её назвали и т.д.

Comment: let humanInfinite = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Infinite", recursively: true)

Comment: заменил humanNode на humanInfinite

Comment: Хм, а проверьте саму ноду правильно ли ее определяет и затягивает ли ее вообще

Comment: ну анимация 3д модельки запускается и все работает. вроде бы это значит что нода определяется нормально, я не знаю как ее перетянуть в функцию свайпа, что бы она там работала

Comment: Если вы анимацию не кодом запускаете то проверьте ноду в коде

Comment: извиняюсь за свое незнание, а это как? :D

Comment: попробуйте заменить run на runAction(rotateAction)

Comment: не получается. не буду Вас мучать =) спасибо за помощь и выделенное время

Comment: Попробуйте так, просто я не совсем понимаю где вы вызываете let humanInfinite = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Infinite", recursively: true) и сохраняете ли вы ее куда-то. Покажите весь контроллер если не получится по второму варианту

Comment: в общем я не знаю как импортировать ноду и все что с ней связано с viewDidLoad() и прописал ее заного в функции для свайпа, заработало.

Comment: @IBAction func rightSwipe(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/human.scn")!
        
        let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
        
        scnView.scene = scene
        
        let rotateAction = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, duration: 1) // создаем екшн
        
        let humanInfinite = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Infinite", recursively: true)
        
        humanInfinite?.runAction(rotateAction)
        
        
    }

Comment: апдейтнул ответ

Comment: огромнейшее спасибо, выручили. без вас бы никак =)